# Adding an object to array values

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am not sure if title correctly relates to my problem, feel free to amend it! :)

What i am trying to do is, visit a m x n matrix in java and simultaneously *mark* the visited nodes based on certain condition

```
    //int a[][] = new int[5][5];
for(int i = 0;i< a.length;i++) //row
        for(int k = 0;k<a[0].length;k++) //column
            if((i+k) % 3 ==0 ) //condition
                a[i][k].visited = true;
            else
                a[i][k].visited = false;
```

In memory, i am imagining it something like :

```
 _ _ _ _
|       |       
|a[0][3]| - > Visited //(for true)  
|_ _ _ _|
```

But i am getting Error :

> visited can not be resolved or is not a field

Can some one please help me on how to *mark* array blocks, or for instance, *associate any value* to them, like, just for example :

```
a[i][i].name = "Boston"
a[i][i].country = "India"
```

**Dummy Program I am using**, similar to my actual code

```
class TestingGround {

    int a[][] = new int[5][5];
    boolean visited = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestingGround tg = new TestingGround();
        tg.runner();

    }

    void runner()
    {
        for(int i = 0;i< a.length;i++)
            for(int k = 0;k<a[0].length;k++)
                if((i+k) % 3 ==0 )
                    a[i][k].visited = true;
                else
                    a[i][k].visited = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of a ? If it is int, then there is no property in int named visited. Can't we change the code to a[i][k] = 1;//1 = visited Or maybe change the array type to Boolean and use something like a[i][k]= true;

Comment: `a` contains numeric values which are distance, take it as a graph holding distance between 2 different places denoted by `i` and `k`...so i have to mark the *city* that i have visited already, to avoid infinite loops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made your two dimensional array using `int`, so you can only set each one to an integer value.

In order to be able to set things like `.name` or `.country` you need to make an array of class objects that contain your requirements.

Eg: describe your object (note: this is just a simple example, and should be improved)

```
public class MyObject
{
    public String name;
    public String country;
}
```

Then elsewhere:

```
MyObject arr[][] = new MyObject[5][5];
arr[0][3].name = "SomeName";
```

Comment: i added my complete *dummy* code, i have declared *visited* in my class...its just i am not able to relate!!

Comment: What do you mean by relate?

Comment: Primitives like `int` don't have fields you can set. All you can do with them is math and assignment. What's he's saying is that if you want to set a specific field what you need is an array of some kind of object that has the field(s) you want to set - not an array of primitives. Does that make sense?

Comment: In other words, `a` **cannot** be an `int` array if you want to set some property of it

Answer (score 1):

When you access an array using the `name[index]` notation, what you're doing is accessing the object at that index in the array. The methods you can call on this object depend on the static type of the array when you create it (casting can get around this, though). For example, `String[] array` means `array` is an array of `String` objects, so if you do `array[i]` the methods you can perform are those you can perform on `String` objects.

Thus, if you want to mark array blocks in the manner you describe in your question, the objects contained in the array have to be objects that have the fields you desire; in your case, `a` has to be an array of objects that have `name` and `country` fields. You made your array an `int` array, and as `ints` are primitives they do not have any fields; thus, the compiler can't figure out what you mean by `a[i][k].visited` and so gives you an error.

If you have a single flag (`visited` in your case), one possible option is to hold a second array that simply marks whether that position has been visited, but that probably isn't the most efficient way of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

**For doing this array needs to be collection of `Object` not `primitive types`.**

```
int a[][] = new int[5][5];
```

and

```
a[i][k].visited = false;
```

Obviously you can't do this.

But what about this

```
MyClass mc[][]=new MyClass[5][5];
```

Than you can access `Visited` which is `boolean` declared in class for that object.

```
class MyClass
{
public boolean Visited;
    public MyClass(boolean b)
    {
       Visited=b;
    }
}

mc[0][0]=new MyClass(true);

//Then, access that variable

mc[0][0].Visited=false;
```

*Note:You can not associate any variable to primiive value because it's not world famous **Object**.*

What you are trying to do is

```
a[0][0]----->Say 5
a[0][0].Visited=false-------> 5.Visited=false;(OOppss!!! Dosen't make any sense.)
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing , `a[i][k].visited` can not be executed. because you are trying to access visited using 2d array object. and 2d object is an int array object its not having `visited` with it

anything if you want to access it must be available within that object.

so define one class which should have visited boolean.

create a class like this

```
class Matrix{

boolean visited;
}
```

then you can use like

```
Matrix m[][] = new Matrix[10][10];

and set m[0][0].visited = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare an `int` array and expect it to contain a variable named `visited` in it. You need to create an array of Objects.

`MyClass[][] myClassArray = new MyClass[5][5];` \\ Each index refers to `MyClass` instance

and your `MyClass` definition should have the variable `visited` declared

```
class MyClass{

public boolean visited;    

}
```